# PHP Image Upload, with preview on select of a file

Tags: php, javascript, forms, upload, onchange

Ok so im making an image uploader with a chance to see what you are going to upload, before entering it into the database. My mind is kinda tired, could you please just get me through this one? thx (btw it doesnt work :p) Its on a clean page, i choose a file from my pictures on compouter, it doesn echo "hi wazzup

```
   <?php 
 if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
 echo "hi wazzup!";

}

 ?> 

<form name="form" id="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" >
<input type="file" name="image" onChange="if(event.propertyName=='value') {document.getElementById("form").submit();}">
</form>
```

Comment: "Chance of seeing what you're going to upload" = Filename, preview or thumbnail?

Comment: if it echos anything at all ill be happy

Comment: Problem is, even if i put echo "something", it doesnt echo it

Answer (score 0):

See what is the output and you will know wheater your javascript is wrong or you should use $_FILES instead of $_POST for image

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST))
{
   if(isset($_FILES['image'])){
      echo "<span style=\"z-index:1000;display:block;\">hi wazzup!</span>";
    }
echo "POSTED";
}
?>
```

Comment: Its echoing POSTED upon loading the page, with no user entry :(, i dont know where the javascript goes wrong either. Any tips?

Comment: Ok then in this case can you take a hidden field in your form and set its value to something like DOIT and then in post check wheater its value is there or not . Wheather hidden field value is printing or not on submit. Please see it can be that your file input tag is calling submit onchange before it sets value for file tag of html

Comment: edited it to onChange="alert(this.value)". And it only alerted when i selected a file from my computer! Can it be that $_POST doesnt pick up a certain value? Also, the form auto posts if not if(isset($_POST['image'])){    ..... im wondering if if(isset($_POST['THIS VALUE'])){ what value its picking. THANKS

Comment: ok i just changed it onChange="submit();" instead of all the bs in there lol

Comment: so now whats the effect ? is if working as you want ? Form will be posted only the post THIS VALUE have a value in it. isset keyword checks the post parameter and if found only then it form post section will be executed. if there is no value for it then it will not go inside. (this is if i am understanding your ques correctly)